# How to know `on_behalf_of_content_owner` for Youtube Analytics API?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-analytics-api

I want to use `list_batch_report_definitions` method in Youtube Analytics API V2.

http://www.rubydoc.info/github/google/google-api-ruby-client/Google/Apis/YoutubeAnalyticsV1/YouTubeAnalyticsService#list_batch_report_definitions-instance_method

But I don't know what is `on_behalf_of_content_owner` and how to get it.

Comment: I'm not a channel owner but service provider. So I want to get it with API if possible.

Answer (score 0):

> [onBehalfOfContentOwner](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/reference/rest/v1/jobs.reports#Report)  string
>
> The ID of the content owner for whom the API request is being made. If the request does not specify a value for this parameter, the
> API server assumes that the request is being made for the user's own
> channel.
>
> [ID](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/) Identifies the YouTube channel or content owner for which you are >retrieving YouTube Analytics data.

[Note](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/): Content owner reports are only accessible to YouTube content partners who participate in the [YouTube Partner Program](https://www.youtube.com/yt/creators/get-started.html?noapp=1).

I suspect once you have been accepted into this partner program you will be given access to the content owner id.

Comment: Thanks, but how to get the ID? Do you know which API is useful to get it?

Comment: You need to contact your youtube partner account manager. They can tell you how to get it.